# PHP file_get_contents works from one server, but gives an authorization error on

Tags: php, http, authentication

I've got a script that loads information from another page, using the following code:

```
    $creds = 'user:password';
$base64 = base64_encode($creds);

$base_url = 'http://example.com/page.html';
$data = file_get_contents($base_url.$path, false, $auth);
```

This works fine from one server (my local one, using Ubuntu) but gives me the following headers when run from an external server:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.7a DAV/2 SVN/1.6.6 PHP/5.3.14   JRun/4.0 Server at ww2.rch.org.au Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Is there anything in particular I should be looking for here?  I already have allow_url_fopen set to true on both servers if it helps.

*Edit:* Sorry, there was some other code in there that needed removing.  $auth is as follows:

```
$auth = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'    => array(
  'header'  => 'Authorization: Basic '.$base64
  )
));
```

$auth is a stream context, containing the authorization header.

Comment: What's `$auth`? Have you supplied the *correct* user and password?

Comment: funny, you never use `$base_64`, and where u init `$auth`?

Comment: Edited the question to show where $auth and $base_64 are used.  Probably should have included these in the first place.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Yes, the details are correct - one of the first things I say is that it works fine from one server, but not the other.  I copied this script to the new server and that's when it broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) there is no "auth" parameter.

HTTP credentials are usually added in this format:

```
http://username:password@example.com/page.html
```

Comment: While this is contrary to what I originally read as an authorization example, this does work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is basically correct, though, naming a variable as `$auth` doesn't necessary mean that the parameter is `auth`. `$auth` in OP's code is a stream context, which is not incorrect.